# Object.keys and hsOwnProperty js functions are not working in Karate version 0.9.5

Tags: karate

Previously i was using karate version 0.8.0. After migrating to 0.9.5 all of my functions where i am using `Object.keys` and `hasOwnProperty` starts giving me error `TypeError: available.hasOwnProperty is not a function`.

In above code `available = {
  "123": {
    "57": 2
  }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes these are not supported, as a general rule - use JS only for logic, we don't even advise using JS for loops: https://github.com/intuit/karate#loops

Please use the [`karate.keysOf()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-keysof) instead, and there are many more similar API-s for other cases.

Comment: want to ask you one more question.My api's response is very complex that's why in most of the cases i used JS.Most of my testcase depends on different different logic and for that I created a separate feature file containing only JS functions.Now how can I you ```karate.keysOf()``` in that

Comment: @GauravKinra ask a new, specific, simple question as to what you want to do

Comment: Ok @Peter I am posting a question for the same.