# what to use in place of Object.keys and hasOwnProperty when using karate version 0.9.5?

Tags: karate

```
* def a =
    """
      function(ths,tsa,hcia) {
        karate.log(JSON.stringify(tsa[hcia[0]],null,2))
        var fas = (Object.keys(tsa[hcia[0]]))[0]
        karate.log("fas " + fas)
        var art = null
        for(prtsj in ths[hcia[0]]) {
          karate.log(JSON.stringify(ths[hcia[0]][prtsj].sku,null,2))
          if((Object.keys(ths[hcia[0]][prtsj].sku)).indexOf(fas) > -1) {
            art = ths[hcia[0]][prtsj].type
          }
        }
        return art
      }
    """
```

Comment: sorry, I'm not going to break my head trying to understand your code. I leave it others unless you can simplify this and explain what you want to achieve

Comment: I have created one feature file which contains only js functions and most of our code depends on these functions but after upgrading the karate i'm encountering the above mentioned errors.

Comment: ok see my answer. if you want a more helpful answer, ask a more helpful question

Answer (score 0):

Please use [`karate.keysOf()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-keysof) - which will return a JSON array of strings.

Now you can do whatever you want.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61139167/143475